# Store position and values of non-NA elements

Tags: r

I have a data set consisting out of a matrix with quite some NAs. From this, I want to create a dataframe storing both the location and the value of the non-NA values. Via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599602/5785085) `which` can be used to get the locations, via `tempList <- which(!is.na(dummy),TRUE)`. 
Currently I use a for loop afterwards. Is there a better way to add the values?

Data:

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "#000000FF", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "#000000FF", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L))
```

Desired result:

```
structure(list(x = c(8, 7), y = c(5, 7), colour = structure(c(1L, 
1L), .Label = "#000000FF", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Current code:

```
tempList <- which(!is.na(dummy),TRUE)
changedDF <- data.frame(tempList[,1],tempList[,2])
names(changedDF) <- c("row","column")

for(i in 1:nrow(changedDF)){
  changedDF$colour[i] <- dummy[changedDF[i,1],changedDF[i,2]]
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: You can further shorten it to just: `changedDF <- data.frame(tempList, color = dummy[tempList])`.